# Problem with USB wifi LB-LINK WN155A Driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb

I have a usb wifi LB-Link WN155A, I try many method but still cannot work.

I have two wireless interface, one is PC and other is a usb wifi. PC wifi interface work OK but I cannot make usb wifi work.

For the module, I also try to compile mt and rtl ko, but fail.

Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-38-generic`
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter

sudo lshw -numeric -class network

*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation [8086:24FD]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 78
       serial: f8:63:3f:3b:dc:ab
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=192.168.10.151 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 memory:dc100000-dc101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V [8086:15D8]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 21
       serial: f4:4d:30:6e:78:a9
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:128 memory:dc200000-dc21ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlxec3dfddbdbdb
       serial: ec:3d:fd:db:db:db
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

```
$ifconfig 
wlp58s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:63:3f:3b:dc:ab  
      inet addr:192.168.10.151  Bcast:192.168.11.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::757f:9c2b:d5e1:7ff6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:14472 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2852 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:17545226 (17.5 MB)  TX bytes:398195 (398.1 KB)

wlxec3dfddbdbdb Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:3d:fd:db:db:db  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I try to download driver (8192cu and 8188eu)

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
8188eu                724992  0
ccm                    20480  6
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
rfcomm                 77824  2
rtl8xxxu              122880  0
rtl8192cu              73728  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        57344  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
bnep                   20480  2
arc4                   16384  4
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
```

after I build module, I try to use `modprobe`, but it show

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8188eu.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic
```

I also try to modify `/etc/network/interface`. But it still fail.

## Update

compile `mt7601` error

```
/declanlc-driver-mt7601usta/src/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:120:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   init_timer(pTimer);
   ^
/declanlc-driver-mt7601usta/src/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:121:9: error: ‘OS_NDIS_MINIPORT_TIMER {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
   pTimer->data = (unsigned long)data;
         ^
/declanlc-driver-mt7601usta/src/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:122:20: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   pTimer->function = function;
                    ^
```

Comment: You have no less than *three* drivers loaded for the USB. They are probably conflicting. Why did you feel the need to download and compile yet another driver? What is not working as expected? Why do you need two wireless devices working at the same time?

Comment: @chili555 Finally will use one of the wifi device only. We will disable other wifi device.

Comment: Frankly, I suspect that your built-in Intel would out-perform any USB. I suggest that you abandon the USB and troubleshoot the Intel.

Answer (score 0):

Requiered for all installations 

`sudo apt install -y git build-essential make autoconf libtool gcc gettext linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

now you can try to install your drivers

but before i recommend to try installing the

mt7601 driver

`git clone https://github.com/declanlc/declanlc-driver-mt7601usta.git
cd declanlc-driver-mt7601usta/src
make
mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
insmod os/linux/mt7601Usta.ko`

should this not work then try your mentioned drivers

rtl8188eu:

`git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
cd rtl8188eu
make all
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8188eu or 8188eu`

rtl8192cu:

`git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192cu
cd rtl8192cu
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu or 8192cu`

Comment: I got problem when I compile driver. I edit the post

Comment: do: echo "blacklist mt7601Usta" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and restart before trying again.